# Groovy Grails tool suite installation

Tags: grails, groovy, ggts

I am trying to pick up Grails using Groovy Grails tool suite. I tried to set up the tools to play around with Grails, unfortunately this issue which will need some advise. Please help me to resolve this problem.

[image: This is picture showing the error while trying to create a new Grails project at GGTS]

[image: Another picture on more errors]

These are the tools I had installed, using window 7:
1. Java JDK  (jdk1.8.0_101)
2. Grails 2.3.4 
3. Groovy Grails Tool Suite 3.5.1

Both Java and Grails are running fine. @cmd:

```
C:\Users\00Who00>java -version
java version "1.8.0_101"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_101-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.101-b13, mixed mode)

C:\Users\00Who00>grails -version
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option PermSize=32m; support
 was removed in 8.0
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; sup
port was removed in 8.0
Grails version: 2.3.4
```

Answer (score 2):

Grails 2.3 doesn't work with Java 8 because of the version of Groovy it uses; you need to use a newer version that uses a version of Groovy that's compatible. Either user Grails 2.4+ (or embrace 2016 and use an even more recent version) or switch to Java 7.

Comment: Thanks Burt Beckwith, I get it now. Initially I had the latest version of Grails and Java installed but GGTS doesn't support them and tried to move back ward to the older versions, hoping the older version works. Once again thanks for the information

Answer (score 2):

If you're getting started with Grails and attempting to use GGTS and Grails 2.3, I suspect you might be reading *Grails in Action 2nd Ed*. A fantastic book! Regardless, a couple of things to note:

- Groovy-Grails Tool Suite has been [discontinued](https://blog.pivotal.io/pivotal/news/groovy-2-4-and-grails-3-0-to-be-last-major-releases-under-pivotal-sponsorship) for over a year, so is quite likely to have more issues
- Grails 3.x is the latest and much improved (Gradle and Spock are defaults, among many other things)

For an IDE, I suggest switching to IntelliJ IDEA. If you are using Grails 3, both Ultimate and Community editions work fine since Grails 3 uses Gradle as a build tool. I'd definitely recommend the Grails 3/IntelliJ combo for getting up to speed, even if you need to switch back to 2.3 for work purposes. Nearly all the knowledge will transfer.

**Available Grails 3 resources**

There are no books yet on Grails 3 specifically. Here are some of the best resources I've found.

- Grails 3 talks at SpringOne: [infoq.com/conferences/springone2gx2015](https://www.infoq.com/conferences/springone2gx2015)
- Grails 3 User Guide: [docs.grails.org/latest/guide/single.html](http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/single.html)
- MrHaki's "Grails Goodness" series (which he offers compiled as a book also): [mrhaki.blogspot.com/search/label/Grails%3AGoodness](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/search/label/Grails%3AGoodness).

Beyond those, the [Grails in Action 2nd Ed](https://www.manning.com/books/grails-in-action-second-edition) book is still very relevant and one of the best ways to get a comprehensive understanding of Grails.

Comment: Thanks thecodesmith! I will try out IntelliJ IDEA.  Is there any good tutorials or books to recommend for Grails 3.x? Most of the tutorials or books I found are based on Grails 2.x.

Comment: Right now there are no books on Grails 3 specifically. Here are some of the best resources I've found. Grails 3 talks at SpringOne: https://www.infoq.com/conferences/springone2gx2015. Grails 3 User Guide: http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/single.html. MrHaki's "Grails Goodness" blog posts (which he offers compiled as a book also): http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/search/label/Grails%3AGoodness. Beyond those, the Grails in Action 2nd Ed book is still very relevant and one of the best ways to get a comprehensive understanding of Grails.